# jekyll markdownify not working like i thought it would

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to work off a Jekyll template:

https://github.com/nathanrooy/Clean-and-Simple-Jekyll-Theme

I want to modify the About, but when I edit the text in Index.md:

https://github.com/nathanrooy/Clean-and-Simple-Jekyll-Theme/tree/master/about

it doesn't parse the markdown, I just wind up with the markdown as regular text in the result. I've tried using markdwonify with no luck, i.e:

{% capture m %}I am an associate professor of [electrical engineering](http://www.ee.cooper.edu) at [The Cooper Union](http://www.cooper.edu) {% endcapture %}{{ m | markdownify }}

Results in:

{% capture m %}I am an associate professor of [electrical engineering](http://www.ee.cooper.edu) at [The Cooper Union](http://www.cooper.edu) {% endcapture %}{{ m | markdownify }}

In my resulting webpage.

Is there anyway I can get Jekyll to parse the markdown in this page?

Comment: Origin code is useless. What's important to help you is your markdown and the resulting html, not your theme. A repository url is a must.